# CSS Won't be loaded at Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Internet Explorer (Latest Version) is not able to load my css while Chrome, Safari, Firefox are having no trouble loading the css.

My style files are correctly connected to the html page using the following line:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="Pages/style.css" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Pages/Index/index.css" type="text/css">`

My site Configuration is like this:

- Public Html (Folder)

  - Database (Folder)

    - (Nothing Inside Here)
  - Pages (Folder)

    - Icons (Folder)

      - IconA
      - IconB
      - IconC
    - Index (Folder)

      - index.css (Secondary Style Sheet)
    - style.css (Primary Style Sheet (Which I'm going to use for all my pages))
    - general.js (All my javascript Jquery is inside here)
  - index.html (Main Html Page)

You can visit my site here: [rk.r4u.nl](http://rk.r4u.nl), but remember it will only work with chrome.

**Solution:**

I struggled a whole day finding the problem and at the end it was the @media {} in my css which I used to keep my codes clean that caused the css file to not load.

Comment: You're referring to `Pages/style.css`, yet your file list shows `Pages/index.css`.

Comment: Typo it should be style.css sorry, I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

It should belike this.
Use forward slash `/` instead of backward slash `\`.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="Pages/style.css" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Pages/Index/index.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: You are using backward slash .Use forward slash / instead of backward slash \.

Comment: Thanks! It works on Firefox now but it still doesn't work on internet explorer

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be a caching problem. Clear your cache and check.

Comment: I can suggest you to change this at the top of the CSS file:  <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for the code that would be helful.

Comment: I checked you website you are not adding <meta charset="utf-8"> above the CSS files. Add <meta charset="utf-8"> before writing the css file.

Comment: Adding <meta charset="utf-8"> before the css only breaks the firefox functionallity and make Internet Explorer not work neither :(